# Upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04, "Oh no! Something has gone wrong."

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

So I followed this guide to upgrade https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today (using the GUI option), and then I just left my laptop do its work since a have an errand to run. When I came back, my laptop's already in login screen, tried to log in but can't seem to go through so I tried to restart. The boot process is unnaturally long, over 15 mins, then it's just white screen showing "Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occured and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator."

Done some research and did everything everyone said, no dice.
I tried to boot to recovery and sudo apt-get update, no errors. Then I do sudo apt-get upgrade and it says that dpkg was interrupted and I have to run sudo dpkg --configure --a manually, so I did and I don't see any errors. Tried to reboot and the same message happens.

I'm a newbie in Linux world so any help is appreciated, my hardware is a Acer laptop, Intel CPU with Nvidia graphics card. Thank you.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong/1239036#1239036

Comment: Hey @Ollie, thanks for answering. I did ctrl + alt + F3 thing and typed my password, but only greeted by the white/error screen afterwards. I did what the poster below you said, too, but still no results from my side...