# "Unassigned login" after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade

Tags: 20.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.1 yesterday.  Everything seemed ok, except some icons looked strange, so I rebooted the computer.  Now I'm seeing an error screen and can't log in:

```
Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator
```

I tried following the advice on [After Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04: “Oh no! Something went wrong”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong/1239036#1239036) but immediately encountered a problem.  After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> I am taken to a black screen that says:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS unassigned tty3  
  
unassigned login:
```

I've tried all the login credentials I have and always receive the message "Login incorrect".

I'm new to this process - is there something I'm missing?  What is unassigned login?  There is some data I'd like to save - are there steps I can try to recover the account since it doesn't seem to recognize my login credentials?