# Oh no! Something has gone wrong. Please contact system administrator

Tags: boot, xubuntu

Whenever I boot my computer I get the message

> Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
> A problem has occured and the system can't repair. Please contact a system administrator

Here is an image -

[image: Oh no! Something has gone wrong]

It happened after a restart !! BTW graphics and other drivers are up to date , I can still acesss tty and grub recovery

I have seen [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong) but it isn't helpful at all, it just says to update but don't tell how to solve this problem.

---

@matigo requested to tell that how I installed Xubuntu

So As I mentioned before, I just purged ubuntu desktop and installed Xubuntu

```
sudo apt --purge autoremove gnome* 
sudo apt --purge autoremove ubuntu-desktop*
sudo apt --purge autoremove gdm3*
sudo apt install tassel
sudo tasksel install xubuntu-desktop
```

However after running these I could still see ubuntu on login screen but I wasn't able to log into it so I removed Ubuntu from -

```
/usr/share/xsessions
```

But however after sometime, I wanted ubuntu-desktop back on my sibling's request,  So I tried to do

```
sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
```

(I did this before rebooting the changes of xsessions directory) After this I rebooted the system and broke into the error

After that I tried reinstalling gdm3 and ubuntu-desktop,  xubuntu desktop, several time, I tried to switch to lightdm too.

### Edit-2

I did this command by chance

```
sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm && sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Now I am getting the login screen, but my desktop environments are still acting crazy

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-1kDry5x1qUqIQxKvtxKX7dG-l4o-qTH/view?usp=drivesdk]

I don't know what is happening

If I choose Ubuntu or gnome or Xubuntu I get the same error "Oh no! Something has gone wrong....".

Only LXQT is working, reinstalling don't work even now please help me to restore Ubuntu desktop.

---

My system info:
OS: Xubuntu 21.10 Impish (It is Ubuntu only but I removed Ubuntu desktop and installed Xubuntu )
Kernel 5.13.0.21
RAM : 16 GB
Storage : 2TB only 67GB is used
CPU: Intel i9