# Update to 22.04 on Dell Latitude E7440

Tags: boot, 22.04

I updated on both my laptop and desktop. Desktop had no problem apart from an issue with the Dock. But the laptop had screen lock set..and I could not access the PC during the upgrade as it gave me authentication error. When the activity light stopped, I rebooted..hoping that it had all gone well and would restart. But now I keep getting a message saying "Oh! No! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system cannot recover, please contact a system administrator" I have tried rebooting holding down the F8, F12 keys and no change in message....have I bricked it?

Comment: "bricked" refers to hardware that no longer works (it has the same usefulness of a brick). You should be able to reinstall the system. This may be the best option if you have multiple issues which it seems may be the case.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The same way you installed it in the first place?

Comment: If you need a refresher, you can follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong

This is what solved it for me.