# USN-5469-1 Did others get a bad upgrade or just me?

Tags: boot, upgrade

After getting this upgrade today I could not fully reboot my computer. I don't know if that is technically correct, since grub came up as always, but after I tried to log in on the gui, I got a white screen that said "something went wrong" - no details - and gave me a button to log out and try again. But three retries all failed, at which time I went into grub and just went back from 5.4.0-117 generic to 5.4.0.-113 generic and it came up fine.

Are there any details about this? Things I should do to protect my system? What do I do about any future updates? etc. Thanks.

Edit / update 2022-06-20 @ 12:34 CDT
Today I looked at [After Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04: "Oh no! Something went wrong"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong)  and  [How do I resume a release upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade)  which seem close to my issue, however, I am not aware of any network loss or power failure during my upgrade as most of the posters there describe. I also found this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099952/sudo-apt-get-install-f-removed-all-packages-from-debian  which offered this advice:

> apt-get install -f will try to fix the package dependencies of the installed system* using whatever means necessarily. Usually this means just removing the broken package

*I take this to mean on the one that broke, 117, not the working one I fell back to, 113. But if I went back to 117 and then ran this command, will I even get a terminal window, or just more white screens that only allow me to log out?

Comment: I also have the same problem and I tried this https://askubuntu.com/a/41939/1603681

Comment: @JaloliddinQarshiyev : Thanks, but you say you tried this - do you mean the accepted answer? Did that work for you? I haven't seen anything labelled 'kernel panic' so I'm not sure it's the same thing. What about the other answers?