# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS "Oh no something went wrong please contact your administrator"

Tags: startup

I was trying to install DrRacket for my cs class. So I went to racket site and it led to this [site](https://launchpad.net/%7Eplt/+archive/ubuntu/racket)
I copied and pasted these commands from there.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plt/racket
sudo apt update
```

and I did all the steps for installing it.
Installation was successful and racket was working. But after logging out and login. It is showing "Oh no something went wrong. Contact your administrator"

Searching on internet I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong), still didn't work

If it is any helpful running `tail /var/log/syslog`
shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX4uh.jpg).

edit:
Sorry if my question was unclear. I meant that my Ubuntu os shows "Something went wrong" not the racket app. [Photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kftTw.jpg)

@David I don't know the version, I'm new to Ubuntu so I was just copying and pasting commands from internet. I might have pasted something and broken something while installing racket.

Comment: Do you know that this app works with Ubuntu 22.04? They do have their own site site https://launchpad.net/~plt You may want to check there and find out.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot

Comment: Look at this other site I found. Is this what you installed? https://launchpad.net/~plt/+archive/ubuntu/racket/+build/24354920

Comment: I have edited the question please check it