# Ubuntu 22.10 Oh no ! Something has gone wrong

Tags: login

I have Ubuntu 22.10 and got the error report "Oh no ! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again." when I want to log in.

It's not a fresh installation, I used it like two months already, but today my window was frozen, I restarted with alt+print+s u b and since then I get this error message and I can't log in.

I tried much I read online, like `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, but all my packages are fine now and I still can't log in.
Furthermore, I noticed, that the cogwheel icon, which I can switch between Wayland, Xorg, and gnome and unity, has now disappeared.

Has anyone an idea how I can fix this?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04: "Oh no! Something went wrong"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah the problem was with gnome, the solution '$ sudo apt-get remove gnome-session gnome gnome-shell
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop' helped me. now it works fine :)