# "Oh no! Something went wrong!" and unable to fetch package archives

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Turned on my PC today and got greeted with a white screen stating "Oh no! Something went wrong. Please contact your system adminstrator."

Started by looking this up found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong) question. Attempted to do CTRL-ALT-F3 but got greeted with a black screen with a blinking cursor and unable to type anything. Decided to try and boot in recovery mode and access the root terminal there. Continued with the answers given in that question and tried to install packages using `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` etc, however, I am getting "failed to fetch" errors on all the archives. I check my internet connectivity using `ping www.google.com` and I get `Temporary failure in name resolution`. Attempting `ping 8.8.8.8` or `ping 8.8.4.4` gives me `Network is unreachable`. Time to look up fixes for this.

Most of the fixes state to check the `/etc/resolve.conf` file and modify it to use Google DNS servers with `8.8.8.8` and/or `8.8.4.4`. Add these to the `/etc/resolve.conf` file and I get the same results.

What do I do? Pretty sure I just need to fix whatever the issue is with internet connectivity to download packages, and then that should fix my "Oh no! Something went wrong" issue.

Comment: Is your Network Manager active at the time you get the `Network is unreachable` message? Check with `systemctl status network-manager` (assuming you use Network Manager). If it's inactive, try restarting it.

Comment: Ah ok so I rebooted from recovery mode and managed to get into the login by using `CTRL-ALT-F3` and from there I could do the package updates successfully, however, I still get the "something went wrong" white screen when I try to reboot again

Comment: Did you do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, `sudo apt install -f` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`? These may solve the `Oh no!" problem, and ought to be harmless otherwise.

Comment: When logging in via the terminal, I get prompted to do a `do-release-upgrade` to ubuntu 23.04, so I'm gonna try and see if that works

Comment: I did `sudo dpkg --configure -a` already but not the other 2

Comment: Ayyyyy the `do-release-upgrade` has fixed it. So I'm guessing networking must be disabled when in the root terminal in recovery mode and I think that's a pretty safe bet. As for the "oh no!" message, other questions seem to solve it. I assume that my system must have upgraded a package required for 23.04 without my updating to that version? I have no idea. Anyway it works now so it's all good