# I updated Ubuntu 22 and got "Oh no something has gone wrong!"

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

The error message is "System can't recover. Please contact a system administrator."

I have run commands as per previous questions related to such an error:
->sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
->sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04: "Oh no! Something went wrong"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong)